# Weird question about natural numbers. Obvious or not?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given any subset $A,C \subset \Bbb{N}$, there exists a maximal subset $B \subset \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $b \in B, a \in A, \ |b - a| \in C$.

For instance $A = \{3,5\}$, $C = \{2,4\}$, then $B=\{7\}$ it seems.

Comment: Won't $B=\Bbb N$ be *the* only such maximal?

Comment: @Asaf: Not at all. For example, $6\notin B$ in the example given.

Comment: Why do you say $B=\{7\}$ is maximal? What's wrong with $B=\{1,7\}$?

Comment: @Cameron: Right. I read the variables in the wrong order.

Comment: @Asaf: I did the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just let $B=\{a+c:a\in A,C\in C\}\cup\{a-c:a\in A,c\in C\text{ and }a>c\}$.

Comment: I think you want $B = \{b \in \mathbb N:  \text{for all } a \in A, |b - a| \in C\}$.  (This is by definition the set of all $b$ that we can allow in $B$.)  In the example given, your set would include (e.g.) $b = 5 + 4 = 9$, which fails for $a = 3$.

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

The (admittedly, not very revealing) answer is $$B=\left\{b\in\Bbb N:\forall a\in A\bigl(\lvert b-a\rvert\in C\bigr)\right\}.$$ By definition, any set with the property you described will be a subset of this one.